# Lua global table different in different files

Tags: android, lua, lua-table, luajava

I use the [AndroLua](https://github.com/mkottman/AndroLua) port of LuaJava on Android and when I define a global table in file A and try to access it from file B some entries are missing:

file A:

```
Game = {
  name = "name"
}

function Game:init()
  self.score = 7
  self.player = "othername"
  require('B')
end
```

The `Game:init()` method is called from java.

file B:

```
require('A')

print(Game.score) -- nil
print(Game.player) -- 'name'
```

Why does file B not print '7' and 'othername'?

Comment: Thi is not working code. It has syntax error. And also you can not load neather A or B file because of loop.

Comment: Yes you are right, I'm calling the Game:init() method out of java so it is no loop

Comment: It should work `c.lua` `require "A" Game:init()` prints `7` and `othername`

Comment: So the problem is somewhere in the AndroLua implementation of the `require()` function :(

Comment: I just noticed that tostring(Game) returns a different table name in A and in B. This is strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error in file A: A function should end with `end`, not `}`.

You should have got an error message like this:

```
error loading module 'A' from file './A.lua':
    ./A.lua:9: unexpected symbol near '}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the `require('A')` in file B.